# How to loop transpose function for every row containing a specific character on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

This is what I have (each "|" symbol indicates a new column on the same row)

```
John | Doe
Manager
NY
123-45-67
Fax: 987-54-32
a@b
Jane
Assistant
CA
234-56-78
c@d
Mike | Brown
Analyst | Intern
CA
345-67-89
e@f
```

However, I am trying to get it to look like the below on Google Sheets:

```
John Doe | Manager | [empty] | NY | 123-45-67 | Fax: 987-54-32 | a@b
Jane | Assistant | [empty] | CA | 234-56-78 | [empty] | c@d
Mike Brown | Analyst | Intern | CA | 345-67-89 | [empty] | e@f
```

The names are all formatted in bold font so I can use that property as my identifier to be able to merge last names and first names into the same column. However, not sure how I can leave a column empty if a fax number exists in one record and it doesn't in another.

I ultimately want it to be able to create a new record row after each cell that has a "@" character in it. How much of this is possible? If it can be done, how much of it can be done and how can it be done in Google Sheets?

Comment: Why would you want analyst and intern in different columns? Then your states won't all line up in the same column?

Comment: All are possible through apps script.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is great to know. What would that script be like for Google Sheets? I will probably need to create empty fields for some rows so that phone numbers are aligned all in the same cloumn etc.

Comment: It'll look like JavaScript, because that's what Apps Script uses. If this is just a one-off and not something that will be run regularly, I would probably just use the copy-paste transpose and then sort the sheet so I could insert cells as needed to align row content. Otherwise you will need to write some fancy logic to get the script to recognize what content is in each cell.

Answer (score 0):

It took some work, but this can be done without a script, through use of built in functions in the sheet. I will put a link to an example below in a comment, but I cannot promise to keep it there forever. But here is the method.

STEP 0: Add appropriate headers in row 1 for sanity. Reserve column A for a record locator, to be built later. Thus, in the example above "John" sits in B2 and "Doe" is in C2.

STEP 1: Build a column for each type of field, and indicate whether the value is that type. For instance, my column D determines if something is an email with the (draggable) formula `=iferror(find("@",B2)>0,false)`. In column E I determine if something is a name. You could use the bolding idea, but I went for `=or((row()=2),D1)`, which says either I am the first row of data, or the preceding row was an email. This too gets dragged. Similarly to test for states: `=and((LEN(B2)=2),(B2=upper(B2)))`, fax `=(upper(mid(B2,1,3))="FAX")`, ID `=and((len(B2)=9),mid(B2,4,1)="-",mid(B2,7,1)="-")`, and finally anything else must be a job `=not(or(D2,E2,F2,G2,H2))`.

STEP 2: Construct the value from the 2 potential columns. If the second is empty, just the first. Otherwise names get a space between and anything else gets "and" between. `=if(ISBLANK(C2),B2,if(E2,B2&" "&C2,B2&" and "&C2))`

STEP 3: Construct the record type based on which things were true. I put the type names in the header row, so they will match later, which makes this formula a bit impenetrable, but I hope you get the idea: `=if(D2,$S$1,if(E2,$N$1,if(F2,$P$1,if(G2,$R$1,if(H2,$Q$1,if(I2,$O$1,"error"))))))`. Now in A2 I append the record number to the job type, where the record number is how many names we have met so far, thus (also draggable) `=K2&countif($E$2:$E2,true)`. [The idea of building a key this way comes from [Prashanth](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-in-google-sheets/)

STEP 4: I left column L blank for neatness so the results are separate from the input and calculations, and then I put a record number in column M as follows `=(row()-1)`. And now we apply vlookup across the rest of the row to get each field by matching it to the column header of the desired output (name|job|state|ID|fax|email) as follows `=vlookup(N$1&$M2,$A:$K,10,false)`, which is built to be draggable both to the rightmost column (email) and the bottom row (row 4 for record 3, in our example). Missing data show up as #N/A (if you find that ugly, an IfError can make it say something nicer).

I hope this illustrates not only a result, but also a method, with which you could tinker if you saw fit.

Comment: As promised, here is a link to the example data, executed as described above https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mb9OzGLQIW4VHZnhNgkBYHidkGLun9Dsz4SpL2c4zYk/edit?usp=sharing